# There is a way to update all properties of an object, changing only it values?

Tags: c#, reflection

So, i have this object for exemple:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public List<User> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

So, there is a way to update a `User` object, updating it `Children` and `Cars`?
If there isn't a car in the object to update that there is in the new object, add it, but if there is in the object to update and there isn't in the new object, remove it from the object to update, and update all attributes for all cars that are matched, and also to the `Children`property.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. This is possible.

Comment: What has reflection to do with this?

Comment: Because if there isn't a native method to this, probabily i have to create a custom method that 'll use reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It's possible, here the solution (this solution update all properties, class properties and collection properties, but if there is an class inside, the class needs to inherit of an AbstractEntity):

```
private void UpdateAllProperties<idType, entityType>(entityType currentEntity, entityType newEntity)
    where idType : IEquatable<idType>
    where entityType : AbstractEntity<idType>
{
    var currentEntityProperties = currentEntity.GetType().GetProperties();
    var newEntityProperties = newEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var currentEntityProperty in currentEntityProperties)
    {
        foreach (var newEntityProperty in newEntityProperties)
        {
            if (newEntityProperty.Name == currentEntityProperty.Name)
            {
                if (currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
                    currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(AbstractEntity<>))
                {
                    var idPropertyType = currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty("Id").PropertyType;
                    var entityPropertyType = currentEntityProperty.PropertyType;

                    this.InvokeUpdateAllProperties(currentEntityProperty.GetValue(currentEntity, null),
                                                    newEntityProperty.GetValue(newEntity, null),
                                                    idPropertyType, entityPropertyType);

                    break;
                }
                else if (currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(
                            x => x.IsGenericType &&
                                    x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)))
                {
                    dynamic currentCollection = currentEntityProperty.GetValue(currentEntity, null);
                    dynamic newCollection = newEntityProperty.GetValue(newEntity, null);

                    this.UpdateCollectionItems(currentEntityProperty, currentCollection, newCollection);

                    dynamic itemsToRemove = Enumerable.ToList(Enumerable.Except(currentCollection, newCollection));
                    dynamic itemsToAdd = Enumerable.ToList(Enumerable.Except(newCollection, currentCollection));
                    dynamic itemsAreEqual = Enumerable.ToList(Enumerable.Intersect(currentCollection, newCollection));

                    for (int i = 0; i < itemsToRemove.Count; i++)
                    {
                        currentCollection.Remove(Enumerable.ElementAt(itemsToRemove, i));
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < itemsToAdd.Count; i++)
                    {
                        currentCollection.Add(Enumerable.ElementAt(itemsToAdd, i));
                    }

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentEntityProperty.SetValue(currentEntity, newEntityProperty.GetValue(newEntity, null), null);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateCollectionItems(PropertyInfo currentEntityProperty, dynamic currentCollection, dynamic newCollection)
{
    var collectionType = currentEntityProperty.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Where(
                            x => x.IsGenericType &&
                                    x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)).First();

    var argumentType = collectionType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    if (argumentType.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
        argumentType.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(AbstractEntity<>))
    {
        foreach (var currentItem in currentCollection)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in newCollection)
            {
                if (currentItem.Equals(newItem))
                {
                    var idPropertyType = currentItem.GetType().GetProperty("Id").PropertyType;
                    var entityPropertyType = currentItem.GetType();

                    this.InvokeUpdateAllProperties(currentItem, newItem, idPropertyType, entityPropertyType);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void InvokeUpdateAllProperties(dynamic currentEntity, dynamic newEntity, dynamic idPropertyType, dynamic entityPropertyType)
{
    var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("UpdateAllProperties", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(idPropertyType, entityPropertyType);
    genericMethod.Invoke(this, new[] { currentEntity, newEntity });
}
```

An exemple of the usage:

The AbstractEntity:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<idType>
    where idType : IEquatable<idType>
{
    public idType Id { get; set; }
}
```

The exemple classes:

```
public class User : AbstractEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Car> OtherCars { get; set; }
    public Car MainCar { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Car other)
    {
        if (this.Id == other.Id)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class Car : AbstractEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Car other)
    {
        if (this.Id == other.Id)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the method:

```
User currentUser = new User()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Vinicius",
    OtherCars = new List<Car>()
    {
        new Car()
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Corsa II",
            Color = "Azul"
        },
        new Car()
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Palio",
            Color = "Vermelho"
        },
        new Car()
        {
            Id = 4,
            Name = "Fusca",
            Color = "Azul"
        }
    },
    MainCar = new Car()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Corsa",
        Color = "Preto"
    }
};

User updatedUser = new User()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Vinicius Ottoni",
    OtherCars = new List<Car>()
    {
        new Car()
        {
            Id = 5,
            Name = "Voyage",
            Color = "Azul"
        },
        new Car()
        {
            Id = 6,
            Name = "Voyage II",
            Color = "Vermelho"
        },
        new Car()
        {
            Id = 4,
            Name = "Fusca",
            Color = "Rosa"
        }
    },
    MainCar = new Car()
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Voyage",
        Color = "Vinho"
    }
};

this.UpdateAllProperties<int, User>(currentUser, updatedUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to just set the `Cars` and `Children` properties in the target object to refer to the `Cars` and `Children` lists in the source object.

```
originalUser.Cars = changedUser.Cars;
originalUser.Children = changedUser.Children;
```

This may not be possible, though if the objects have been created in different ORM contexts.

The alternative is to compare the lists and modify the objects appropriately.  you'd need to write a method to do this.  LINQ would be very helpful.

**Update**

Here's a quick and dirty (and probably VERY inefficient) extension method that could be useful:

```
public void UpdateUser(this User user, User changedUser)
{
    var changedUserCarIDs = changedUser.Cars.Select(c => c.Id).ToArray();
    user.Cars = user.Cars.Where(c => changedUserCarIDs.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();
    foreach (var changedCar in changedUser.Cars)
    {
        var car = user.Cars.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == changedCar.Id);
        if (car == null) user.Cars.Add(car = new Car());
        car.Name = changedCar.Name;
        car.Color = changedCar.Color;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want one helper method that can update any object type, then yes, you'll need to use Reflection.  BUT, depending on what you're really trying to do this is probably the wrong solution.  You can go a long way with generics and judicial use of the `dynamic` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

To find added and removed:

```
var removedCars = orgUser.Cars.Except(changedUser.Cars);
var addedCars = changedUser.Cars.Except(orgUser.Cars);
```

Use the equality comparer overload to find all changed cars: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx

Do the same thing for the children.