# Add text to all properties in all items of a list without manual multiple loops

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of MyClass

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


var records = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass { Title = "Mr", Name = "Bob" },
    new MyClass { Title = "Dr", Name = "Jon" },
};
```

I need to add "" around each value in each property of the class, and each item in the list. So the actual content of each property contains a " at the start and end.

Is there a way I can add this without having to loop through each property & item and do it all manually. A way using Linq perhaps?

I can't find anything on Google, I'm not even really sure what to search for.

Thanks

Comment: why "without loop"? this seems a strange requirement.Note that every possible LINQ solution will loop internally.

Comment: Implementing JSON serialization by hand this way is strange :)... Anyway https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516235/there-is-a-way-to-update-all-properties-of-an-object-changing-only-it-values has all pieces you'd need to construct "foreach list item / foreach property" code.

Comment: @GianPaolo So why does anyone ever use Linq? :D - just because I'd like to learn more Linq and learn ways to make my code more elegant / shorter.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not doing that though it looks like it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, simply map the transformation:

```
var transformedRecords =  
    records.Select(c => 
        new MyClass 
        { 
            Title = $"\"{c.Title}\"",
            Name = $"\"{c.Name}\"" 
        });
```

Now, if what you want is a way to edit all `string` properties without having to manually change them one by one, then the only way is with reflection:

```
static void Transform<T>(T t)
    where T: class
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(t, null))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));

    var propertiesToEdit =
        typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                BindingFlags.Instance)
                 .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)
                             p.CanWrite &&
                             p.CanRead);

    foreach (var p in propertiesToEdit)
    {
        p.SetValue(t, $"\"{p.GetValue(t)}\"");
    }
}
```

But now you've got a method that mutates the object that is passed into it. You should never use mutating methods with LINQ, unexpected behaviors are to be expected.

So you are better of just simply iterating manually:

```
foreach (var r in records)
    Transform(r);
```

And now your `records` list will contain the mutated items.

Of course, you don't need to stop at `string`, you can make this quite a bit more general with very little additional cost:

```
static void Transform<T, Q>(T t, Func<Q, Q> transform)
    where T: class
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(t, null))
       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));

    var propertiesToEdit = 
        typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                BindingFlags.Instance)
                 .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Q)
                             p.CanWrite &&
                             p.CanRead);

    foreach (var p in propertiesToEdit)
    {
        p.SetValue(t, transform((Q)p.GetValue(t)));
    }
}
```

And now you'd use it like this:

```
foreach (var r in records)
    Transform(r, (string s) => $"\"{s}\"");
```

The `class` constraint is important here because this will fail with value types; c# defaults to pass by value semantics so the method will mutate copies, not the original instances in the list.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Missed that. Updated answer, LINQ is not the way to go here because you essentially need to mutate the list members.

Comment: Nice update. You are setting right expectations with "unexpected behaviors are to be expected" :)

Answer (score 0):

Without using a loop I believe this is what you seek:

```
 records.ForEach(e => 
        {
            e.Name = $"\"{e.Name}\"";
            e.Title = $"\"{e.Title}\"";
        });
```